# jQuery input field .val() is undefined

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm having a problem with an error: jQuery input val() is undefiend.
I have 3 inputs which are referring to one item.

On add Row i can add an new Item ( 3 rows ).

All those rows have to be prepared in array to be sent to a PHP file.

I believe that my `id="item[0]['name']"` is wrong.

```js
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var counter = 1;
            $("#addRow").click(function() {
                $("#ItemContainer").append(`
                    <div class="item">
                        <div><input type="text" id="item[${counter}]['name']"   placeholder="Name"   ></div>
                        <div><input type="text" id="item[${counter}]['amount']" placeholder="Amount" ></div>
                        <div><input type="text" id="item[${counter}]['count']"  placeholder="Count"  ></div>
                        <div></div>
                    </div>
                `);
                counter = counter + 1;
            });

            $("#setKasse").click(function() {                   
                for (let i = 0; i <= (counter - 1); i++) { 
                    console.log($(`#item[${i}]`));
                    console.log($(`#item[${i}]["name"]`).val());
                };
            });
        });
```

```css
*{
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
        body{
            background-color: #E6E6FA;
            color           : #191970;
            padding-left    : 5%;
            padding-top     : 70px
        }
        #Container, #ItemContainer, .item {
            width: 20%;
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: 1fr;
            grid-template-rows: auto;
            row-gap : 18px;
        }
        #ItemContainer, .item{
            width: 100%;
            row-gap : 2px;
        }

        input{
            height: 30px;
            width: 100%;
            border: none;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            padding-left: 4px;
            font-size: 14px;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Container">
        <div><button id="addRow"> Add Row </button></div>
        <div id="ItemContainer">
            <div class="item">
                <div><input type="text" id="item[0]['name']"   placeholder="Name"   ></div>
                <div><input type="text" id="item[0]['amount']" placeholder="Amount" ></div>
                <div><input type="text" id="item[0]['count']"  placeholder="Count"  ></div>
                <div></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div><button id="setKasse"> Set Kasse </button></div>
    </div>
```

So, I want a way to be able to cycle and loop into objects|Arrays

My main goal is to send the data via Ajax Post request, and for that I want to refactor the Array in another Format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In selectors, `[` is used to indicate an attribute selector. If you want to use it as a literal character in the ID, you need to escape it with backslash. You also need to escape the `'` characters.

You also need to include the `['name']` part of the ID (or `['amount']` or `['count']` if you want to get those inputs).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var counter = 1;
  $("#addRow").click(function() {
    $("#ItemContainer").append(`
                    <div class="item">
                        <div><input type="text" id="item[${counter}]['name']"   placeholder="Name"   ></div>
                        <div><input type="text" id="item[${counter}]['amount']" placeholder="Amount" ></div>
                        <div><input type="text" id="item[${counter}]['count']"  placeholder="Count"  ></div>
                        <div></div>
                    </div>
                `);
    counter = counter + 1;
  }); // end of $("#addRow").click

  $("#setKasse").click(function() {

    for (let i = 0; i <= (counter - 1); i++) {
      console.log($(`#item\\[${i}\\]\\[\\'name\\'\\]`).val()); 
    }

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Container">
  <div><button id="addRow"> Add Row </button></div>
  <div id="ItemContainer">
    <div class="item">
      <div><input type="text" id="item[0]['name']" placeholder="Name"></div>
      <div><input type="text" id="item[0]['amount']" placeholder="Amount"></div>
      <div><input type="text" id="item[0]['count']" placeholder="Count"></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div><button id="setKasse"> Set Kasse </button></div>
</div>
```

In my opinion, it's best to avoid using characters that have special meaning in CSS selectors in your IDs, it complicates the code unnecessarily. You could use `id="item-${counter}-name"`. Or don't use IDs for dynamically created elements at all. Use a class like `class="name"`, and then use dynamic indexing. `$(".item").eq(i).find("input.name")`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var counter = 1;
  $("#addRow").click(function() {
    $("#ItemContainer").append(`
                    <div class="item">
                        <div><input type="text" class="name"   placeholder="Name"   ></div>
                        <div><input type="text" class="amount" placeholder="Amount" ></div>
                        <div><input type="text" class="count"  placeholder="Count"  ></div>
                        <div></div>
                    </div>
                `);
    counter = counter + 1;
  }); // end of $("#addRow").click

  $("#setKasse").click(function() {

    for (let i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
      console.log($(".item").eq(i).find(".name").val()); 
    }

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Container">
  <div><button id="addRow"> Add Row </button></div>
  <div id="ItemContainer">
    <div class="item">
      <div><input type="text" class="name" placeholder="Name"></div>
      <div><input type="text" class="amount" placeholder="Amount"></div>
      <div><input type="text" class="count" placeholder="Count"></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div><button id="setKasse"> Set Kasse </button></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I see, Very informative. i didnt understand the part of the class and dynamic indexing. would you min if you wrote the part of code so i can see it? Thank you

Comment: Thanks @Barmar, I'll never use any strange characters in my `id`s, since I want to make my life easier.